# Load-balanced URL for Central Administration?

Tags: central-administration, load-balancing

We have six servers in our SharePoint 2010 farm. Two servers have the Central Administration application. We would like to have a load-balanced URL for CA but beforehand would like to know the positive and/or negative of it.

Do you suggest having a load-balanced URL for CA?

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking about SP2010, but I assume [this definitive guide (for SP2007) on the subject written by Spence Harbar](http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx) still applies.

Comment: Spence to the rescue again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your AAM with the load balanced URL.

I've not had issues with this configuration.  I can't think to many cons, other than taking a bit more effort to deploy on multiple servers.  Benefits are clearly the instant access to CA should you lose a server.

I do take special care to ensure I've stopped the services on the other servers before doing updates, but other than that I don't do anything special.